# why my node Js project is not working by using vs code live server extension but it is working using npm node server

Tags: html, css, node.js

I installed npm node server and installed live server extension in vs code but my project is not running using live server extension but it is working using npm server

I want to know why using live server my project is not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could be different Node versions.